# How to add kinda Event to vb.net Custom Control?

Tags: vb.net

Made a custom control which is a panel, with a text box and button inside it, pressing the button will show up open file dialog for user to select a file.

Once user has selected the file, its full path + name will be copied to the text box.

The problem: Need to do a validation on the file name before accepting it and copying it to the text box, but this validation cannot be done inside my custom control, so need to pass the selected file name back like an event and give an option to accept/reject it after verification, (true/false).

How to implement that process to send back the file name and wait for a true/false return value to continue? inside custom control?

I hope I was clear :(

Comment: You need to show the code here.  You've got full control over what happens between the user selects the file and it being displayed in the text box

Comment: Firstly, if you didn't, what you should have done is created a user control. You add a user control to a project in basically the same way you add a form - there's a dedicated menu option for it. You then design and code the user control in exactly the same way you would a form. Once you build, the user control will appear in the Toolbox and you use it like you would any other control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're talking about is not "like" an event but IS an event. I would suggest that you use a cancellable event, i.e. one whose second parameter - the `e` parameter - is type `CancelEventArgs`. [Here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html) is my blog post on the subject of custom events and it includes that type of event. I suggest that you read that in its entirety but I'll provide a specific example of what you want here.

Here is an example of a user control that matches your description that includes such an event:

```vb
Public Class FileSelector

    Public Event FileSelected As EventHandler(Of FileSelectedEventArgs)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Using dialogue As New OpenFileDialog
            If dialogue.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                Dim fse As New FileSelectedEventArgs(dialogue.FileName)

                OnFileSelected(fse)

                If Not fse.Cancel Then
                    TextBox1.Text = fse.FilePath
                End If
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnFileSelected(e As FileSelectedEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent FileSelected(Me, e)
    End Sub

End Class
```

When the `Button` is clicked, an `OpenFileDialog` is displayed. If the user clicks *OK*, the `FileSelected` event is raised. Here is the `FileSelectedEventArgs` class used there:

```vb
Public Class FileSelectedEventArgs
    Inherits System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs

    Public ReadOnly Property FilePath As String

    Public Sub New(filePath As String)
        Me.FilePath = filePath
    End Sub

End Class
```

That class inherits `CancelEventArgs`, so it has a `Cancel` property, and it also adds a read-only `FilePath` property. Here's an example of how you might handle that event in a form:

```vb
Private Sub FileSelector1_FileSelected(sender As Object, e As FileSelectedEventArgs) Handles FileSelector1.FileSelected
    e.Cancel = (Path.GetDirectoryName(e.FilePath) <> My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments)
End Sub
```

That event handler gets the file path and validates it - in this case, checks whether the file is directly in the user's *Documents* folder, and cancels the event if and only if the path is invalid. Looking back at the user control code, the selected file path is displayed in the `TextBox` if and only if the `FileSelected` event is not cancelled.

Comment: @FrankHolloway, I have updated my answer with a specific example.